# On load Edit page Image value be filled

Tags: php, jquery, image, laravel, edit

Can someone please tell me how can I take the  input value of an image on Edit

```
<img src="{{url('/')}}/images/answers/{{ $option->id }}/medium/{{ $option->image_path }}"  id="image{{ $i }}">
<input value="{{url('/')}}/images/answers/{{ $option->id }}/medium/{{ $option->image_path }}" onchange="readURL(this, {{ $i }});" type="file" name="image{{ $i }}" id="<?php echo 'answer_file'.$i;?>" />
```

I tried something like this I putted on value the same url as in the image but it is not working, the image src is working fine I can see the images , but my problem is that when I change one photo all the others are deleted, so I want all the input photos to be filled so when I click edit these photos that I did not touch the choose file button to not be erased I want their old value to be taken.Hope someone can understand my problem.

Comment: Try it using the helper `asset` like this `<img src="{{asset('/images/answers/'. $option->id .'/medium/'. $option->image_path)}}"  id="image{{ $i }}">
 <input value="{{asset('/images/answers/'. $option->id .'/medium/'. $option->image_path)}}" onchange="readURL(this, {{ $i }});" type="file" name="image{{ $i }}" id="<?php echo 'answer_file'.$i;?>" />` !!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but this is not working, it is giving me the same result, I have 4 pictures and they appear just fine, when I click upload file and than submit, only the one that I changed is appearing the others are gone..

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You cannot auto-fill an input type file due to security reasons. Only the user can fill the file type input

One possible solution is to have the id of the model in order to know what image to delete, and then add another one (replacing)

Answer (score 0):

i belive you have `$option` in your backend rest its just constant, so you can figure it out without passing it.
otherwise you may use js to pass this like so:

```
<input value="$('#image{{$i}}).attr('src')" onchange="readURL(this, {{ $i }});" type="file" name="image{{ $i }}" id="<?php echo 'answer_file'.$i;?>" />
```

hope this help